# Need Help rearranging the database

Tags: arrays

I got an example list (txt.file) from the database that I need to rearrange to:

[image]

[image: Target Database layout]

Since the size of the data from the original database is too large to process in Excel. I would have to consider using commands to help me to achieve this transformation.

In the Original Database pic: only some row consist of a number that its the VAF number. When that number is present, the Target Database would print those data out for that specific patient.

If the patient has multiple mutations like "KMT2D" the columns will be combined and separated by ";"

I am really stuck with this database atm and hopes someone can show me a working script to help me solve this issue.

Much appreciated.
Paul

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. **Show us the code for your latest attempt** and where you got stuck. and explain why the result is not what you expected.  Edit your question to include the code, please don't add it in a comment, as it will probably be unreadable.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

It is better to show what is actually happening, rather than describing what you expect to happen.

Please include code and output as content for your question, **not as pictures** or external links.

Comment: Please can you tell us what type of database you intend to use? That may affect the answers considerably.